# unable to authenticate against Twitter Streaming API to search on hashtags

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, streaming

i've been working on this all day to no effect. i've tried this script using the Twitter libraries out there for PHP, but I've had little luck. I went through the Twitter docs and a lot of examples to get to my current code. I'm not getting a bearer_token back.

1) I've set up a dev account.
2) I've generated keys and tokens.

Please help.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$hashtags="#Pistorious #OscarPistorious #PistoriousTrial";
$hashtags = str_replace("#", "%23", $hashtags);
$hashtags = str_replace(" ", "+", $hashtags);
$query=rawurlencode($hashtags);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$oauth_key = CONSUMER_KEY;
$oauth_nonce = substr(md5(rand()),0,32);
$oauth_timestamp = time();
$oauth_token = ACCESS_TOKEN;

$key = '';
$key .= rawurlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET);
$key .= '&';
$key .= rawurlencode(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

$oauth_hash = '';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_consumer_key="{$oauth_key}"&';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_nonce="{$oauth_nonce}"&';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_timestamp="{$oauth_timestamp}"&';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_token="{$oauth_token}"&';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_version=1.0';

$base = '';
$base .= 'POST';
$base .= '&';
$base .= rawurlencode($url);
$base .= '&';
$base .= rawurlencode($oauth_hash);
$base .= $query;

$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));

$oauth_header = '';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_consumer_key="'.$oauth_key.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_nonce="'.$oauth_nonce.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature="'.$oauth_signature.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_timestamp="'.$oauth_timestamp.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_token="'.$oauth_token.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_version="1.0", ';

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"; // url to send data to for authentication
$headers = array( 
    'POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1', 
    'Host: api.twitter.com', 
    'User-Agent: my Twitter App v.1',
    "Authorization: OAuth $oauth_header",
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8', 
    'Content-Length: 76',
    'Connection:close',
    'Accept:*/*'
); 

$ch = curl_init();  // setup a curl

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  // set url to send to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // set custom headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // send as post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials"); // post body/fields to be sent
$header = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // send custom headers
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$retrievedhtml = curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl
curl_close($ch); // close the curl
$output = explode("\n", $retrievedhtml);
$bearer_token = '';
foreach($output as $line) {
    if($line === false)
    {
    // there was no bearer token
    }else{
    $bearer_token = $line;
    }
}
if (false!=$bearer_token) {
    $bearer_token = json_decode($bearer_token);
    curl_close($ch);
    $headers = array( 
    "GET /1.1/search/tweets.json".$url." HTTP/1.1", 
    "Host: api.twitter.com", 
    "User-Agent: testapp",
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$token."",
    );
    $curl_request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $formed_url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl_request);
    $err=curl_error($curl_request);
    if ($err!="") {
        echo curl_error($curl_request);
    }
    else {
        curl_close($curl_request);
        var_dump($response);
        echo 'done';
    }
} else {
    echo 'didnt authenticate against server';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

It now works. After I canned the code and used TwitterAPIExchange/j7mbo. After THAT didn't work before.